# Using HIbernate / Spring whats the best way to watch a table for changes to individual records?

Tags: spring, hibernate, watch

**Q:** What is the proper way to watch a table for record level changes using Hibernate / Spring? The DB is a typical relational database system. Our intent is to move to an in-memory solution some time in the future but we can't do it just yet. **Q:** Are we on the right track or is there a better approach? Examples?

We've thought of two possibilities. One is to load and cache the whole table and the other is to implement a hibernate event listener. Problem is that we aren't interested in events originating in the current VM. What we are interested in is if someone else changes the table. If we load and cache the entire table we'll still have to figure out an efficient way to know when it changes so we may end up implementing both a cache and a listener. Of course a listener might not help us if it doesn't hear changes external to the VM. Our interest is in individual records which is to say that if a record changes, we want Java to update something else based on that record. Ideally we want to avoid re-loading the entire cache, assuming we use one, from scratch and instead update specific records in the cache as they change.

Comment: Have you considered using database triggers? That would be the most reliable way to immediately perform some callback.

Comment: Is it possible to fire off a java process running external to the database with a database trigger and without watching a table? When I considered this, I thought we might watch an auditing table created by triggers if there was one, but either way you are watching a table as far as I know. -- I've since discovered we have some auditing but not enough. Several tables are apparently involved.

Comment: It depends on the features of your database system. Not all of them offer trigger features, and not all of them offer stored procedure (database functions) features. Stored procedures may need to be written in some vendor-specific language (e.g. Oracle's PL/SQL), consisting of basic language features and basic function libraries, e.g. to make HTTP calls or parse XML files. Some database systems support stored procedures written in open languages, such as Java. Even if they don't, though, there may be other ways to bridge a stored procedure call to an external Java main method.